# What's this glassware?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, equipment

Can anybody tell me what this glassware with a stem, bulb and long tube is?

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The glassware shown is a [drying tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drying_tube). The bulb holds cotton or glass/quartz wool while the tube part holds a drying media such as anhydrous calcium sulfate to keep moisture out of the vessel during moisture sensitve reactions.